# Unable to Parse pandas Series to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm importing a csv files which contain a datetime column, after importing the csv, my data frame will contain the Dat column which type is pandas.Series, I need to have another column that will contain the weekday:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = 
pd.read_csv("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Fichiers/Proj/CONSOMMATION_1h.csv")
print(data.head())
```

all the data are okay, but when I do the following:

```
data['WDay'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
print(type(data['WDay']))
# the output is 
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

the data is not converted to datetime, so I can't get the weekday.

Comment: You need to call `data['WDay'].dtype` to see the datatype, what you're seeing is a `pandas` `Series` of possibly `datetime`s

Comment: It is perfectly OK output, each column of `DataFrame` is `Series` ;)

Comment: And what is your code for weekday? Maybe problem is something else.

Comment: thanks to all of you i got the type datetime64[ns]  after that i use data['WDay'] = data['WDay'].weekday     and i got an error :'Series' object has no attribute 'weekday'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you need [`dt.weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) with `.dt`:

```
data['WDay'] = data['WDay'].dt.weekday
```

Without `dt` is used for `DataetimeIndex` (not in your case) - [`DatetimeIndex.weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html):

```
data['WDay'] = data.index.weekday
```

Comment: thank you that worked and i finally understand how this datetime stuff works

Answer (score 1):

use the command `data.dtypes` to check the type of the columns.